# How to run 10 python programs simultaneously?

Tags: python

I have `a_1.py`~`a_10.py`

I want to run 10 python programs in parallel.

I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    I want to execute python program

def f(name):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        subprocess.Popen(['python3', f'a_{i}.py'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

but it doesn't work

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python parallel processing", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  You have to fork off the 10 child processes; your posted code only forks the iterating parent, `f`.  Try `POpen` inside the loop.

Comment: looks like the ideal place for a shell script, Python is overkill for jobs like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of `multiprocessing`:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys


MAX_SUB_PROCESSES = 10

def info(title):
    print(title, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')

    # Create a list of subprocesses.
    processes = []
    for i in range(1, MAX_SUB_PROCESSES+1):
        pgm_path = f'a_{i}.py'  # Path to Python program.
        command = f'"{sys.executable}" "{pgm_path}" "{os.path.basename(pgm_path)}"'
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, bufsize=0)
        processes.append(process)

    # Wait for all of them to finish.
    for process in processes:
        process.wait()

    print('Done')
```

Comment: I don't believe this. You're a genius
I am deeply grateful for your time for my serious difficulty. 
Thank you so much that I cannot express myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to call 10 external `py` scripts (`a_1.py` ~ `a_10.py`) as a separate processes - use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) class:

```
import subprocess, sys

for i in range(1, 11):
    subprocess.Popen(['python3', f'a_{i}.py'])

# sys.exit()   # optional
```

---

It's worth to look at a rich `subprocess.Popen` signature (you may find some useful params/options)

Comment: It does not run simultaneously. OTL

Comment: @GoBackess, that's wrong, it does run simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiprocessing pool to run them concurrently.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(module_name):
    """ Executes a module externally with python """
    __import__(module_name)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_processes = 5
    module_names = [f"a_{i}" for i in range(1, 11)]
    print(module_names)
    with mp.Pool(max_processes) as pool:
        pool.map(worker, module_names)
```

The `max_processes` variable is the maximum number of workers to have working at any given time. In other words, its the number of processes spawned by your program. The `pool.map(worker, module_names)` uses the available processes and calls worker on each item in your module_names list. We don't include the .py because we're running the module by importing it.

Note: This might not work if the code you want to run in your modules is contained inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` blocks. If that is the case, then my recommendation would be to move all the code in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` blocks of the `a_{}` modules into a `main` function. Additionally, you would have to change the worker to something like:

```py
def worker(module_name):
    module = __import__(module_name) # Kind of like 'import module_name as module'
    module.main()
    return
```